# Does intel J1900 have vsync?

Tags: intel, gpu, qt

i am trying to run Qt5 with eglfs on an intel j1900 cpu (HD graphics gen7). when running the app i and getting the error

```
Could not queue DRM page flip on screen DP1 (Invalid argument)
```

looking at the source for eglfs I see on line 294

```
FrameBuffer *fb = framebufferForBufferObject(m_gbm_bo_next);
ensureModeSet(fb->fb);

QKmsOutput &op(output());
const int fd = device()->fd();
m_flipPending = true;
int ret = drmModePageFlip(fd,
                          op.crtc_id,
                          fb->fb,
                          DRM_MODE_PAGE_FLIP_EVENT,
                          this);
if (ret) {
    qErrnoWarning("Could not queue DRM page flip on screen %s", qPrintable(name()));
    m_flipPending = false;
    gbm_surface_release_buffer(m_gbm_surface, m_gbm_bo_next);
    m_gbm_bo_next = nullptr;
    return;
}

for (CloneDestination &d : m_cloneDests) {
    if (d.screen != this) {
        d.screen->ensureModeSet(fb->fb);
        d.cloneFlipPending = true;
        int ret = drmModePageFlip(fd,
                                  d.screen->output().crtc_id,
                                  fb->fb,
                                  DRM_MODE_PAGE_FLIP_EVENT,
                                  d.screen);
        if (ret) {
            qErrnoWarning("Could not queue DRM page flip for clone screen %s", qPrintable(name()));
            d.cloneFlipPending = false;
        }
    }
}
```

http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs/deviceintegration/eglfs_kms/qeglfskmsgbmscreen.cpp?h=5.11#n294

I can't seem to find a way for eglfs to not use vsync, and using the env varibles below dont make a difference

```
QT_QPA_EGLFS_SWAPINTERVAL
QT_QPA_EGLFS_FORCEVSYNC
FB_MULTI_BUFFER
QT_QPA_EGLFS_FORCE888
```